# virtualenv is not activating. 'env' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: python, windows, virtualenv, python-venv

I've created a virtualenv folder (named "env") to use for my Flask app.Used the following command to create the virtualenv:

```
py -3 -m venv env
```

When I'm trying to activate the virtualenv using `env/Scripts/activate` it produces the following error:

> ```
> 'env' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
> operable program or batch file.
> ```

I've python 3.7.4 installed in my computer.
I'm using windows

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bvirtualenv%5D+%5Bwindows%5D+activate

Answer (score 1):

How are you running the command?
If on mac/linux, do `source env/bin/activate`

If on Windows, you need to run the `.bat` file in Scripts

Comment: i'm running activate file from the scripts,according to the documentation given by flask https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/installation/

Comment: Are you on unix or windows?

Comment: i'm on windows.

Comment: You need to run the bat file then,
e.g. C:\Users\'Username'\venv\Scripts\activate.bat

Comment: did that. still no change

Comment: I don't know how but some it is working now. The only thing I did was  replacing env/Scripts/activate command with env\Scripts\activate . Backslash matters

Comment: nice :) care to accept my answer? thanks

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html?highlight=activate.bat